# Error in Colors.xml file "Error: Content is not allowed in prolog."

Tags: android

I have made a new project in the android studio, and this error shows up. I have clean and rebuild the project but this error is not resolving.
[image]

Colors.xml default coding is missing and this auto-generated text is showing.

Comment: Can you try to delete the file and regenerate it?

Comment: I have the same problem, it keeps complaining about XML files that doesn't actually contain XML, and I cannot import JUNIT

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem as shown in the image below:
The first image(Error)
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yihY7.png)

Solution: 
Go to your user folder:
[User Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6EqK.png)

I deleted these two files (.AndroidStudio3.4) and (.gradle).
note/Android will download it automatically

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: thank you very much, i searched for it like 8 hours or more

Answer (score 0):

The encoding in your XML and XSD (or DTD) are different.
XML file header:  `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`
XSD file header: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>`

Another possible scenario that causes this is when anything comes before the XML document type declaration. i.e you might have something like this in the buffer:

```
helloworld<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

or even a space or special character.

There are some special characters called byte order markers that could be in the buffer.
Before passing the buffer to the Parser do this...

```
String xml = "<?xml ...";
xml = xml.trim().replaceFirst("^([\\W]+)<","<");
```

Answer (score 0):

**The "content not allowed in prolog" is actually an error from XML parser. It means that an XML document was expected, but something else has been received.**

colors file is an resource file , you can put your resources under  tag.
You can not put contain in this file like you have done there.

Following is example you can use to understand

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="colorBlue">#000099</color>
    <color name="colorRed">#ff0015</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have added the following code and rebuild the project, but this is still not working.

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Was facing the same issue. Delete or modify all the xml with the resources names what you are using as references. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the error is:

> content is not allowed in prolog

The `colors.xml` file's format should be completely correct, for example:

```
item<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

will cause this error because of **item** misplaced before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 0):

After installing Android Studio (3.5.3) and creating my first Hello Android project, things were smooth and the app ran perfectly fine and I was able to make modification and view them on the Emulator.

However, after few days, I decided to create a new module under the same project or even tried to create a new Android project, I started facing the same issue as yours where it was showing that “Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.” and it was pointing to colors.xml. Nevertheless, when I ran Gradle analysis (Gradle Scripts --> Analyze --> Inspect Code) it showed that most *.xml files in the new project are having same issue. If you open the xml files, it will look sort of corrupted but for some reason, the code got encrypted.

The workaround that really worked for me was replacing the corrupted/encrypted code with the one that I had from my first working project. I build the app and it runs perfectly fine.

The xml files that I  had to revisit were:

```
- colors.xml
- ic_launcher_foreground.xml
- ic_launcher_background.xml
- ic_launcher_round.xml
- ic_launcher.xml
```

This might not be the best solution, but it really worked out for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the `colors.xml` file and pasting a `colors.xml` from another project. It will work well unless you modify your original colors file in this case you need to rewrite it.

Answer (score -1):

Was facing the same issue. Delete or modify all the xml with the resources names what you are using as references. It will work.