# Error:Content is not allowed in prolog after recent update of android plugin 3.2.1,gradle 4.6 , errors in colors.xml and xml files inside the drawable

Tags: android, xml

Here, I am attaching the codes of the above mentioned xml files that comes by default after creating a new project. I have tried invalidating cathes & restart and also clean and rebuild but none of them worked for me. I know the problem is similar to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760578/error-in-colors-xml-file-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog) , but I have not created these files myself, these are being created themselves as I create a new project, earlier these used to be created in correct format but after the updates these are being created in incorrect format.Please someone suggest any solution, is there any bug in this update?

**colors.xml**

```
    /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.** This class was automatically generated by the* gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It* should not be modified by hand.*/package android.su
```

**ic_launcher_background.xml**

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.** This class was automatically generated by the* gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It* should not be modified by hand.*/package android.support.graphics.drawable;

public final class R {private R() {}

public static final class attr {private attr() {}

public static int font = 0x7f040097;public static int fontProviderAuthority = 0x7f040099;public static int fontProviderCerts = 0x7f04009a;public static int fontProviderFetchStrategy = 0x7f04009b;public static int fontProviderFetchTimeout = 0x7f04009c;public static int fontProviderPackage = 0x7f04009d;public static int fontProviderQuery = 0x7f04009e;public static int fontStyle = 0x7f04009f;public static int fontWeight = 0x7f0400a0;}public static final class bool {private bool() {}

public static int abc_action_bar_embed_tabs = 0x7f050001;}public static final class color {private color() {}

public static int notification_action_color_filter = 0x7f060047;public static int notification_icon_bg_color = 0x7f060048;public static int ripple_material_light = 0x7f060053;public static int secondary_text_default_material_light = 0x7f060055;}public static final class dimen {private dimen() {}

public static int compat_button_inset_horizontal_material = 0x7f08004c;public static int compat_button_inset_vertical_material = 0x7f08004d;public static int compat_button_padding_horizontal_material = 0x7f08004e;public static int compat_button_padding_vertical_material = 0x7f08004f;public static int compat_control_corner_material = 0x7f080050;public static int notification_action_icon_size = 0x7f080086;public static int notification_action_text_size = 0x7f080087;public static int notification_big_circle_margin = 0x7f080088;public static int notification_content_margin_start = 0x7f080089;public static int notification_large_icon_height = 0x7f08008a;public static int notification_large_icon_width = 0x7f08008b;public static int notification_main_column_padding_top = 0x7f08008c;public static int notification_media_narrow_margin = 0x7f08008d;public static int notification_right_icon_size = 0x7f08008e;public static int notification_right_side_padding_top = 0x7f08008f;public static int notification_small_icon_background_padding = 0x7f080090;public static int notification_small_icon_size_as_large = 0x7f080091;public static int notification_subtext_size = 0x7f080092;public static int notification_top_pad = 0x7f080093;public static int notification_top_pad_large_text = 0x7f080094;}public static final class drawable {private drawable() {}

public static int notification_action_background = 0x7f09005d;public static int notification_bg = 0x7f09005e;public static int notification_bg_low = 0x7f09005f;public static int notification_bg_low_normal = 0x7f090060;public static int notification_bg_low_pressed = 0x7f090061;public static int notification_bg_normal = 0x7f090062;public static int notification_bg_normal_pressed = 0x7f090063;public static int notification_icon_background = 0x7f090064;public static int notification_template_icon_bg = 0x7f090065;public static int notification_template_icon_low_bg = 0x7f090066;public static int notification_tile_bg = 0x7f090067;public static int notify_panel_notification_icon_bg = 0x7f090068;}public static final class id {private id() {}

public static int action_container = 0x7f0c0009;public static int action_divider = 0x7f0c000b;public static int action_image = 0x7f0c000c;public static int action_text = 0x7f0c0012;public static int actions = 0x7f0c0013;public static int async = 0x7f0c0017;public static int blocking = 0x7f0c0019;public static int chronometer = 0x7f0c001f;public static int forever = 0x7f0c0033;public static int icon = 0x7f0c0036;public static int icon_group = 0x7f0c0037;public static int info = 0x7f0c0039;public static int italic = 0x7f0c003a;public static int line1 = 0x7f0c003e;public static int line3 = 0x7f0c003f;public static int normal = 0x7f0c0049;public static int notification_background = 0x7f0c004a;public static int notification_main_column = 0x7f0c004b;public static i
```

**ic_launcher_foreground.xml**

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.** This class was automatically generated by the* gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It* should not be modified by hand.*/package android.support.graphics.drawable.animated;

public final class R {private R() {}

public static final class attr {private attr() {}

public static int coordinatorLayoutStyle = 0x7f04006d;public static int font = 0x7f040097;public static int fontProviderAuthority = 0x7f040099;public static int fontProviderCerts = 0x7f04009a;public static int fontProviderFetchStrategy = 0x7f04009b;public static int fontProviderFetchTimeout = 0x7f04009c;public static int fontProviderPackage = 0x7f04009d;public static int fontProviderQuery = 0x7f04009e;public static int fontStyle = 0x7f04009f;public static int fontWeight = 0x7f0400a0;public static int keylines = 0x7f0400ba;public static int layout_anchor = 0x7f0400bf;public static int layout_anchorGravity = 0x7f0400c0;public static int layout_behavior = 0x7f0400c1;public static int layout_dodgeInsetEdges = 0x7f0400c4;public static int layout_insetEdge = 0x7f0400c5;public static int layout_keyline = 0x7f0400c6;public static int statusBarBackground = 0x7f040116;}public static final class bool {private bool() {}

public static int abc_action_bar_embed_tabs = 0x7f050001;}public static final class color {private color() {}

public static int notification_action_color_filter = 0x7f060047;public static int notification_icon_bg_color = 0x7f060048;public static int ripple_material_light = 0x7f060053;public static int secondary_text_default_
```

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't XML files, and the error therefore indicates an immediate catastrophic parsing failure.

Comment: Can u suggest any solution to this, as it is happening every time whenever I am creating a new project.

Comment: Solution: Don't store non-XML data in XML files.